# When does slick start the transaction if the DBIO begins with a future?

Tags: slick-3.0

Let's say there's a `DBIO` composed of a `Future` and a `DBIO`, like:

```scala
/* Talks to some http service */
def httpFuture: Future[Unit] = ???

def addDbRow: DBIO[Unit] = MyTable += MyRow(1)

val db: DatabaseDef = ???

val dbio: DBIO[Unit] = for {
  _ <- DBIO.from(httpFuture())
  _ <- addDbRow()
} yield ()

db.run(dbio.transactionally)
```

Does Slick wait until after the future to begin the database transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Slick *does* wait. If you set:

```scala
def httpFuture: Future[Unit] = Future(Thread.sleep(10 * 1000)) // sleep for 10seconds
```

and watch the database logs, you can see that the transaction does not begin until after the future completes.